# Hibernate SQL transformation fails for Enum field type

Tags: sql, hibernate, enums, hql, transformation

I am using a SQL query and then transforming the result using Hibernates's `Transformers.aliasToBean()`.
One of the columns in my query is an enum. The transformation somehow fails for the enum. What should I do? Which datatype should I use? I want more than 1 character to transform the result into my enum type.

This is how the simplified version of my query/code looks like (***b*** is an enum in the table profiles):

```
session.createSQLQuery("select a, b from profiles").setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Profile.class))
                    .list();
```

Exception : `expected type: Foo.ProfileStateEnum, actual value: java.lang.Character`

Comment: do you want to use only **Transformers.aliasToBean** or a **HQL** will do?

Comment: I am writing a native SQL query, hence I guess HQL will not be enough.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Assuming that the java enum type that corresponds to column b is Foo.ProfileStateEnum, the following code snippet should work for you. (I tested with Hibernate 4.1.6)

```
import java.util.Properties;
import org.hibernate.type.Type;
import org.hibernate.type.IntegerType;
import org.hibernate.internal.TypeLocatorImpl.TypeLocatorImpl;
import org.hibernate.type.TypeResolver.TypeResolver;
import org.hibernate.type.EnumType;

Properties params = new Properties();
params.put("enumClass", "Foo.ProfileStateEnum");
params.put("type", "12"); /*type 12 instructs to use the String representation of enum value*/
/*If you are using Hibernate 5.x then try:
params.put("useNamed", true);*/
Type myEnumType = new TypeLocatorImpl(new TypeResolver()).custom(EnumType.class, params);

List<Profile> profileList= getSession().createSQLQuery("select a as ID, b from profiles")
            .addScalar("ID", IntegerType.INSTANCE)
            .addScalar("b", myEnumType )
            .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Profile.class))
            .list();
```

Comment: This definitely looks interesting. I will try it out. Thanks.

Comment: Not working in hibernate 5.x. Am looking for a quick solution for hibernate 5.x.

Comment: For hibernate 5.x try params.put("useNamed", true); instead of  params.put("type", "12");

Comment: For those as absent-minded as me: that part `.custom(EnumType.class, params);` must be typed as is, since it's `org.hibernate.type.EnumType` in there, not your custom `com.company.MyEnumClass`

Comment: It's good idea to use constants instead of strings: `EnumType.ENUM` instead of `"enumClass"` and `EnumType.NAMED` instead of `"useNamed"`.

Comment: @izogfif awesome, less magic - more sense. I wonder if there any constant for `type` and especially `12`

Comment: @IliaNedoluzhko just use Hibernate 5. The magic constant `12` is for Hibernate 4 only.

Comment: For Hibernate 5.x, use:

`StandardBasicTypeTemplate<MyEnum> enumType = new StandardBasicTypeTemplate<>(VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE, new EnumJavaTypeDescriptor<>(MyEnum.class));`

...like the answer below...

Answer (score 5):

I found two ways to achieve it.

1. Use `org.hibernate.type.CustomType` with `org.hibernate.type.EnumType`(put either `EnumType.NAMED` or `EnumType.TYPE`, see `EnumType#interpretParameters`). Like below:

   ```
   Properties parameters = new Properties();
   parameters.put(EnumType.ENUM, MyEnum.class.getName());
   // boolean or string type of true/false; declare database type
   parameters.put(EnumType.NAMED, true);
   // string only; declare database type
   parameters.put(EnumType.TYPE, String.valueOf(Types.VARCHAR));
   EnumType<MyEnum> enumType = new EnumType<>();
   enumType.setTypeConfiguration(new TypeConfiguration());
   enumType.setParameterValues(parameters);
   CustomType customEnumType = new CustomType(enumType);
   ```
2. Another simple way. Use `org.hibernate.type.StandardBasicTypeTemplate` with `org.hibernate.type.descriptor.sql.*TypeDescriptor`. Like below:

   ```
   StandardBasicTypeTemplate<MyEnum> enumType =
           new StandardBasicTypeTemplate<>(VarcharTypeDescriptor.INSTANCE,
                   new EnumJavaTypeDescriptor<>(MyEnum.class));
   ```

Comment: Option 2 definitely seems to be the simplest and worked for me.

Comment: Option 1 works for Hibernate 5.4.32.Final.

Comment: Option 2 worked for me with Hibernate 5.6.5.

Answer (score 0):

**Let's see why you are getting this exception.**

From the question it is obvious that you have used `@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)` annotation for the field *'b'* in you model class. So the field is an **enum for your model class** and a **varchar for your database**. Native SQL is not concerned about you model class and returns what ever is there in the database table as it is. So in your case, the `SQLQuery` you are using will return a  `String` for *'b'* instead of a `ProfileStateEnum` type. But your setter method for *'b'* in the `Profile` class takes a `ProfileStateEnum` type argument.

Thus you get the exception *"expected type: Foo.ProfileStateEnum, actual value: java.lang.Character"*

**You can use Aliasing to solve the problem.**

What I suggest is, alias your column with any name you want and create a setter method for that alias in your model/dto.

For example, **lets alias your column as *'enumStr'.***

Then your query will look like this : "**select a, b as enumStr from profiles**"

Now, create a setter method for that alias in the your `Profile` class.

(Assuming that the enum `ProfileStateEnum` can have any of the two values `STATE1` and `STATE2`)

```
public void setEnumStr(String str){
    /*Convert the string to enum and set the field 'b'*/
    if(str.equals(ProfileStateEnum.STATE1.toString())){
        b = ProfileStateEnum.STATE1;
    } else {
        b = ProfileStateEnum.STATE2;
    }
}
```

Now on transforming, the setter for the alias `setEnumStr(String)` will be invoked instead of setter for the field `setB(ProfileStateEnum)` and the string will be converted and saved to the type you want without any exceptions.

I am a beginner in Hibernate and the solution worked for me. I am using PostgreSQL. But I believe it works for other databases too.