# Hibernate: Issue with mapping Enum Property Type

Tags: java, hibernate, enums

Followed every step mentioned in this [tutorial](http://blog.javachap.com/index.php/enumeration-mapping-in-hibernate/) but still getting following exception:

```
Caused by: org.hibernate.MappingException: Unable to instantiate custom type: org.hibernate.type.EnumType

Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.hibernate.type.EnumType.setParameterValues(EnumType.java:203) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
    at org.hibernate.type.TypeFactory.injectParameters(TypeFactory.java:131) [hibernate-core-4.2.0.Final.jar:4.2.0.Final]
```

**Part 2**

Then I tried using `@Enumerated` itself. Changed hbm to `<property name="gender" column="usr_gender" not-null="true" type="org.hibernate.type.EnumType">`.

Entity class:

```
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
       Gender gender
```

Still getting the same error.

**Part 3**

Update hbm property to `<property name="gender" column="usr_gender" not-null="true" type="string">`.

Kept entity class same. 
Got back to old error.
`Expected type: Gender, actual value: java.lang.String`

**hbm file**

```
<property name="shortName" column="short_name" type="string" not-null="true"/>
<property name="description" column="description" type="string" not-null="true"/>
<property name="gender" column="gender_type" not-null="true" type="string"/>
```

**Entity Class**

```
import javax.persistence.Enumerated;
import javax.persistence.EnumType;

private String shortName;
private String description;
@Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
private Tenant tenant;
```

Comment: Your source of information is simply outdated. Have a look at the [original docs](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.2/manual/en-US/html_single/) matching your used version - especially look for `@Enumerated` annotation.

Comment: @blafasel  Updated my question based on your comment.

Comment: This won't leed to anything. Please show the relevant parts of the configuration and entity class.

Comment: Please show your settters and getters for entity class...

Answer (score 0):

I got the same exception when I tried to create a custom type for my enum field to give it as the type argument to the `addScalar()` method for an  SQLQuery. It is not clear which part of your code throws the exception. But it seems that you are trying to create a custom type to overcome exception due to argument mismatch of setter method for an enum on result transformation. Please see my answer to [Hibernate SQL transformation fails for Enum type field](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633337/hibernate-sql-transformation-fails-for-enum-field-type/40582469#40582469).