# Mapping multiple values enum types with Hibernate Annotations

Tags: sql, hibernate, enums, hql, transformation

In order to map Hibernate query result to a custom class containing an enum, I should do like this [according to this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9633337/hibernate-sql-transformation-fails-for-enum-field-type/13616668) but I don't want to use enum field name but one of its multiple values :

```
Properties params = new Properties();
params.put("enumClass", "MyStatusEnum");
params.put("useNamed", true)

String sql = "SELECT "
    + "PRICE as price, "
    + "COMPANY as companyId, "
    + "NAME as name, "
    + "STATUS as statusEnum "
    + "FROM `FUC**** TABLE WITH SPACE`";

List <Item> items = session.createNativeQuert(sql) // Obliged to use this method 
// with deprecated transformer after because createQuery does not 
// recognize ` escape character and if I use session.createQuery(sql, Item.class), 
// Item is not recognized as an entity ...
    .addScalar(price) // Obliged to do it for all fields just because I need to do it for one field ?!
    .addScalar(companyId)
    .addScalar(name)
    .addScalar(statusEnum)
    .setResultTransformer(Transformers.aliasToBean(Item.class)).list();
```

1) The problem is for MyEnum.AVAILABLE for example, data will not be "available" but an int so this is my enum :

```
public enum MyEnum {
    AVAILABLE(0, 1),
    TO_SENT(1, null),
    ARCHIVED(2, null);

    private final int stateNum;

    private final Integer nextStateNum;

    MyEnum(int stateNum, Integer nextStateNum) {
        this.stateNum = stateNum;
        this.nextStateNum = nextStateNum;
    }
}
```

And I want to map the STATUS (possible values : 0, 1, 2) in DB not to the name but to the first attribute code (stateNum), how to do that ? Coul I apply a function to get enum from code ?

```
Properties params = new Properties();
params.put("enumClass", "Foo.ProfileStateEnum");
params.put("???", "???");
```

2) How to get doc about properties mapping to enum and that for hibernate < 5, we must use params.put("type", "12");, where is corresponding doc ?

Thank you very much,

Answer (score 0):

Answer to 1) : [Mapping Enum Types with Hibernate Example](https://memorynotfound.com/mapping-enum-types-hibernate-example/) is a track I'm testing but I would not use annotation but code.

Answer to 2) : [Class EnumType](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.0/javadocs/org/hibernate/type/EnumType.html)